# How to fix invalid JSON response in swift when using get request in Alamofire?

Tags: ios, swift, rest, api, alamofire

I am creating an app wherein it pulls `PatientList` from API Server and it will display to a `TableView`. Upon checking, it returns `200` status code but falls to `invalidJSON` error. But when I checked in **Postman**, it returns `200` status code and pulls the records properly. I am quite confuse which part of my codes causes the error since I am new in swift. I am seeking help to solve the issue. Below are my sample codes for your references. Thank you so much in advance.

**Patient.swift**

```
struct Patient: Codable {
    let hospitalNumber: Int
    let patientName: String
    let totalAmount: Double

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case hospitalNumber = "hospitalNumber"
    case patientName = "patientName"
    case totalAmount = "totalAmount"
   }
}
```

**APIService.swift**

```
struct PatientList {
    typealias getPatientListTaskCompletion = (_ patientListperPayout: [Patient]?, _ error: NetworkError?) -> Void


    static func getPatientList(doctorNumber: Int, periodId: Int, completion: @escaping getPatientListTaskCompletion) {

        guard let patientPerPayoutURL = URL(string: "\(Endpoint.Patient.patientPerPayout)?periodId=\(periodId)&doctorNumber=\(doctorNumber)") else {
            completion(nil, .invalidURL)
            return
        }

        let sessionManager = Alamofire.SessionManager.default
        sessionManager.session.getAllTasks { (tasks) in
            tasks.forEach({ $0.cancel() })
        }

        Alamofire.request(patientPerPayoutURL, method: .get, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { (response) in
            guard HelperMethods.reachability(responseResult: response.result) else {
                completion(nil, .noNetwork)
                return
            }

            guard let statusCode = response.response?.statusCode else {
                completion(nil, .noStatusCode)
                return
            }

            switch(statusCode) {
            case 200:
                guard let jsonData = response.data else{
                    completion(nil, .invalidJSON)
                    print(statusCode)
                    return
                }

                let decoder = JSONDecoder()

                do {
                    let patientListArray = try decoder.decode([Patient].self, from: jsonData)
                    let sortedPatientListArray = patientListArray.sorted(by: { $0.patientName < $1.patientName })
                    completion(sortedPatientListArray, nil)
                }catch{
                    completion(nil, .invalidJSON)
                    print(statusCode)
                }
            case 400:
                completion(nil, .badRequest)
            case 404:
                completion(nil, .noRecordFound)
            default:
                print("UNCAPTURED STATUS CODE FROM getPatientList\nSTATUS CODE: \(statusCode)")
                completion(nil, .uncapturedStatusCode)
                }
            }
        }
```

**Controller.swift**

```
var patientList: [Patient]! {
    didSet {
       performSegue(withIdentifier: patientListIdentifier, sender: self)
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.latestCreditedAmountTableView.dataSource = self
    self.latestCreditedAmountTableView.delegate = self

    configureTableViewCell()
    showTotalCreditedAmount()
     getDoctorPayoutSummary(doctorNumber: doctorNumber)

}

func getDoctorPayoutSummary(doctorNumber: Int) {
  self.payoutSummary = payoutSummaryDetails
        self.taxRateVatRateLabel.text = "\(self.payoutSummary.taxRate) / \(self.payoutSummary.vatRate)"
        self.getPatientList()
        self.latestCreditedAmountTableView.reloadData()
        return
}

 func getPatientList() {

    APIService.PatientList.getPatientList(doctorNumber: doctorNumber, periodId: currentRemittance.periodId) { (patientListArray, error) in
        guard let patientListPerPayout = patientListArray, error == nil else {
            if let networkError = error {
                switch networkError {
                case .noRecordFound:
                    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "No Record Found", message: "You don't have current payment remittance", preferredStyle: .alert)
                    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
                    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                case .noNetwork:
                    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "No Network", message: "\(networkError.rawValue)", preferredStyle: .alert)

                    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
                    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                default:
                    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "There is something went wrong. Please try again", preferredStyle: .alert)
                    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
                    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            }
            return
        }

        self.patientList = patientListPerPayout

        return

    }
}
```

**JSON Response**

```
[
   {
   "hospitalNumber": null,
   "patientName": null,
   "totalAmount": 31104
   },
   {
   "hospitalNumber": "",
   "patientName": "LastName, FirstName",
   "totalAmount": 3439.8
   }
]
```

Comment: Can you please include the JSON response of the API in the question.

Comment: @ChrisShaw Hi, I edited my question and included the JSON response. Thank you

Comment: In the `JSONDecoder` catch block print the `error` instance.

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON response shows that some of the fields can be null - `hospitalNumber` and `patientName` at least. Also `hospitalNumber` is a string in the JSON - thanks to @Don for pointing out. Your `struct` should also be able to cope with these being nullable by making the mapped fields nullable also. I.e.

```
struct Patient: Codable {
  let hospitalNumber: String?
  let patientName: String?
  let totalAmount: Double

  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case hospitalNumber = "hospitalNumber"
    case patientName = "patientName"
    case totalAmount = "totalAmount"
  }
}
```

You will need to do the same for `totalAmount` if that can ever be null also. Whether the API is correct to return null in any circumstance is of course another question - how a null hospital number or name is useful may need to be addressed.

Make sure you do not force-unwrap the fields when you use them.

Comment: I tried your answer but still, it returns invalidJSON

Comment: @Titus, that's because hospitalNumber is actually returning a String, although an empty one, instead of an Int. Also, you don't need CodingKeys if the names match your JSON.

Comment: @Don I changed it from Int to String, upon checking when I used breakpoints, the values of the variables in struct was pulled but i encountered error `let sortedPatientListArray = patientListArray.sorted(by: { UIContentSizeCategory(rawValue: $0.patientName!) <= UIContentSizeCategory(rawValue: $1.patientName!) })`  with this error **Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)**

Comment: That's because you are force-unwrapping `patientName` - But it can be `nil` - If it is `nil` and you force unwrap it then you will get a crash.,

Answer (score 0):

Just make below changes in your model class. Define your model class variable as `optional` which is not mandatory from APIs.

```
struct Patient: Codable {
    var hospitalNumber: String?
    let patientName: String?
    let totalAmount: Double?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case hospitalNumber = "hospitalNumber"
        case patientName = "patientName"
        case totalAmount = "totalAmount"
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        if let hospitalNumb = try container.decode(Int?.self, forKey: .hospitalNumber) {
            hospitalNumber = String(hospitalNumb)
        } else {
            hospitalNumber = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .hospitalNumber)
        }
        patientName = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .patientName)
        totalAmount = try container.decode(Double.self, forKey: .totalAmount)
    }
}
```

**Note:**

`Codable` OR `Decodable` is not working if the type is different for the same key or you can say like that type is different then specified type.